# Allow empty string in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a column which does not allow null but allow empty string. I toggle the `Allow Empty String` validation property but still get the `A value is required` error when insert data with empty string. As a result, I have to put a white space in that field and then change it to empty string in edit mode. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Paul - *Allow Empty String* is only applicable for string properties in an **attached** data source, so you won't see the option if you're using the intrinsic database.

@Walter - I think you're having the problem because a string property is initialised to *Null*, not an empty string. If you want the *TextBox* to contain an empty string, you'll need to initialise it to an empty string in the in the table's *Created* method, or in the screen's *InitialiseDataWorkspace* method. In SQL Server, this is normal. Null means *nothing's been entered* for the property, whereas an empty string means this property has deliberately been set to *no value*. It's a subtle difference & can easily trip people up.

I hope that makes sense:

Null = the column's value is *unknown* (hasn't been entered)

Blank String = the column's value has been deliberately set to *blank*